# Does $x_n\rightarrow x_0 \implies a^{x_n}\rightarrow a^{x_0}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If $x_n\rightarrow x_0 ,y_n\rightarrow y_0$ then $ x_n^{y_n}\rightarrow x_0^{y_0}$?

Well i think yes because $x_n^{y_n}=e^{y_n\log x_n}$  where I considered without loos of generality $x_n>0$. And since $y_n\log x_n\rightarrow y_0\log x_0$ the problem is solved. But now, how to prove  in general if $x_n\rightarrow x_0 \implies a^{x_n}\rightarrow a^{x_0}$? I know it's intuitive but if we want to pove using just definitons of convergence is not so simple.

Comment: If the first statment is clear for you, then the second should follow easily using the sequence, which is constant $a$.

Comment: Needed: some kind of definition of $a^x.$ [Do you assume here $a$ is real and positive? etc.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. I do remember an [elementary proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_limits#Exponential_functions) of 
$$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{a^x -1}{x}=\ln{a}, a>0$$
or
$$(\ln{a}-\varepsilon)\cdot|x|<a^x-1<(\ln{a}+\varepsilon)\cdot|x|$$
which can be used to [squeeze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) 
$$a^{x_n}-a^{x_0}=a^{x_0}\left(a^{x_n-x_0}-1\right)=
a^{x_0}\cdot(x_n-x_0)\cdot \frac{a^{x_n-x_0}-1}{x_n-x_0}$$